# Each time I change the page in arabic it first switches to english and then to arabic

Tags: javascript

I am working on a multilingual website.I have used google translator code for 
selecting the languages in dropdown. When i tried to translate the website in arabic language it got translated successfully But I cannot navigate in Arabic as, each time I change the page, it first switches to English and then to Arabic. Whereas my requirement is , once Arabic has been selected, the navigation remains stable and consistently in Arabic. Can Anyone help me to resolve this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <title>League of Arab States</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pages/home/styles/home.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en',
        includedLanguages: 'ar,en',
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
        multilanguagePage: true,
        autoDisplay: false
      }, 'google_translate_element');
      $('.goog-te-menu-value').on('DOMSubtreeModified', 'span', function() {
        language = $(".goog-te-menu-value span").html();

        if (language == "Arabic") {
          $(".col-sm-1").css({
            "float": "right",
            "direction": "rtl"
          });
          $(".col-sm-1 img").css({
            "padding-right": "5px"
          });
          $(".col-sm-2").css({
            "text-align": "center",
            "direction": "rtl"
          });
          $(".navbar-nav").css({
            "float": "left",
            "text-align": "left",
            "padding-left": "5px"
          });
          $(".col-sm-4").css({
            "float": "right ",
            "direction": "rtl"
          });
          $(".panel").css({
            "float": "right",
            "direction": "rtl"
          })
          $(".col-sm-8").css({
            "float": "left",
            "direction": "rtl"
          });
          $("footer").css({
            "direction": "rtl"
          })

        }
        if (language == "English") {
          $(".col-sm-1").css({
            "float": "left",
            "direction": "ltr"
          });
          $(".col-sm-1 img").css({
            "padding-right": "5px"
          });
          $(".col-sm-2").css({
            "text-align": "center",
            "direction": "ltr"
          });
          $(".col-lg-4").css({
            "float": "right",
            "min-height": "0px !important",
            "padding-left": "0px !important",
            "direction": "ltr"
          });
          $(".col-sm-4").css({
            "float": "left",
            "direction": "ltr"
          });
          $(".panel").css({
            "float": "left",
            "direction": "ltr"
          })
          $(".col-sm-8").css({
            "float": "right",
            "direction": "ltr"
          });
          $("footer").css({
            "direction": "ltr"
          });
        }

      });
    };
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Iam writing my code snippet  for language selection.

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this question might be off-topic here, you can simply create an Arabic page and an English page, redirect the user to the Arabic page when they select Arabic from the menu, and set all links in the Arabic page to redirect to the corresponding pages in Arabic.

Comment: creating new pages in arabic wont work for me .I want to make it simpler by using google translate